# Laravel cashier recurring subscription with expiration date

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm using cashier with Laravel for subscription. I would like create a recurring subscription with an expiration date like to 6 month or one year. I see I can used ends_at field in subscription table but some methods will be wrong like cancelled() . Have you a better idea ?

Comment: If you don't want the subscription to be automatically renewed after 6 months, then you can do a single charge payment and handle the subscription period by yourself. Otherwise like you said it would be the same as having an canceled subscription and some methods would not work as expected, for which you can wrap the subscription object into another class and implement your own logic.